# How do I plot a course with specific star classes in Elite Dangerous?

Tags: elite-dangerous

Sometimes when I plot a course, I always get fuel-scoopable stars, and at other times, I go for long periods without coming across a scoopable star.

**Question**: Is it possible to plot a course that only has specific star classes? For example, I'd like to plot a course that only visits scoopable stars, and avoids unscoopable stars, even if it isn't as efficient distance-wise.

Answer (score 2):

With some trial and error, I discovered that this is actually possible.

1. Open the **Galaxy Map**
2. Go to the tab with the miniature groupstars on it (directly to the right of Bookmarks)
3. Click on the **Map** style
4. Under Filters, choose **Show By Colour --> Star Class**
5. **Uncheck** every star class except: OBAFGKM
6. Plot your route to a remote star system

You should only be guided to scoopable star classes.

**NOTE**: While the **Apply Filter to Route** option seems like it would be necessary, this actually has a different meaning entirely.

Comment: The common mnemonic to remember the scoopable star classes is "KGB FOAM", but really you just have to remember "M" because it's M and everything before it in the list. You may want to consider leaving the white dwarf and non-sequence stars in, since neutron and white dwarf stars can give you a jump range boost.

Comment: Interesting -- I just learned about the white dwarf types, thanks to you. I had heard about Neutron stars as well, but documentation seems very limited on them at the moment. I haven't used one yet. Got any guidance? Maybe post a separate Q&A?

Comment: @TrevorSullivan If you're going to try neutron-boosted jumping I'd recommend practicing on a white dwarf star that's inside the bubble. The boost isn't as powerful but there's a number of them in populated space. You have to go a bit further to find a neutron star, and if you want to hit the neutron superhighway you're going to have to travel around 7,000 LY to reach it, but it makes getting to Colonia (Jaques Station) *far* faster. I can do 1,000 LY in about 7 jumps on the highway, normally that would be 34+ jumps for my Asp Explorer.